# MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []:

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting an error :

User can create a task from account or contact, on a task contact is a required field, but when a user tries to create a task from contact it fails.

```
   public with sharing class TaskTriggerHandler {

    private boolean trigger_isExecuting = false;

    public TaskTriggerHandler(){

    }

    public void OnAfterInsert(Task[] newObjects){
        // EXECUTE AFTER INSERT LOGIC
        updateAccountActivityFields(newObjects);
    }

    public void OnAfterUpdate(Task[] oldObjects, Task[] updatedObjects, Map<ID, Task> ObjectMap){
        //EXECUTE AFTER UPDATE LOGIC
        updateAccountActivityFields(updatedObjects);
    }

    public void updateAccountActivityFields(Task[] taskRecords){
    /* when a task of RecordType(Safelite_Task_Record_Type) is created/updated either from Account or Contact then 
    update Account fields : Last_Face_to_Face_Activity__c, Last_Visited_By__c & Last_Call_Activity__c based on task type
    */
        // find task record type 
        RecordType taskRec = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType ='Task' AND DeveloperName ='Safelite_Task_Record_Type'];

        //Set of Account IDs getting updated
        Set<ID> aid = new Set<ID>();
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        Account a;

        //Map of Account IDs and Accounts
        Map<id,account> accMap = new Map<id,account>();

        //Get all the contactIds and accountIds of the task being inserted/updated
        for(Task tk : [SELECT Id, LastModifiedBy.name, type, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate, RecordTypeId, whoid, whatid FROM task WHERE id in :taskRecords]){
            if(tk.RecordTypeId == taskRec.Id  && tk.Whoid!=null){

                aid.add(tk.whatid); 
                a = new Account(id = tk.WhatId);

                //convert task's CreatedDate, datetime to date
                Date createdDateJustDate = date.newinstance(tk.CreatedDate.year(), tk.CreatedDate.month(), tk.CreatedDate.day());

                //update the activity fields on account with Task's lastModifiedDate and LastModifiedBy based on Task Type
                if(tk.type=='Face 2 Face Meeting' || tk.type=='Lunch'){
                    a.Last_Face_to_Face_Activity__c = createdDateJustDate;
                    a.Last_Visited_By__c = tk.LastModifiedBy.name;
                }
                else{
                    a.Last_Call_Activity__c =  createdDateJustDate;
                }
                //Populate accMap with the Account IDs and Account record
                accountsToUpdate.add(a);
                accMap.put(a.id,a);
            }
        }
        if(!accMap.isEmpty()){
            Update accMap.values();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that every `Task` has a non-null `WhatId` that is an `Account`. Both facets of this assumption are *not* guaranteed, and your code should check them before you do this:

```
            a = new Account(id = tk.WhatId);
            // ...
            accountsToUpdate.add(a);
            accMap.put(a.id,a);
            // ...
        Update accMap.values();
```

The immediate cause of the error is a `null` `WhatId`, resulting in you trying to update an `Account` whose `Id` field is empty.

As an alternative, you may wish to use the `AccountId` field, which is equal to `WhatId` if it is an Account, or is the `Account` associated with the `WhoId`. (There is some more complex logic behind it). However, this field is *also* not guaranteed to be populated with a non-empty value.

Comment: Thanks for the David, if i try to query and get the whatId from WhoId(since whoID is required on a task, it can not be null). a = new Account(Id = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact  WHERE Id =: tk.WhoId LIMIT 1].AccountId); I'm getting bulkification error and my test class fails when I insert more than 100 records

Comment: I would encourage you to complete the excellent Trailhead module on Apex bulkification to understand that issue. Please also remember that Contacts are not required to be associated with an Account and may have a `null` `AccountId`.

Comment: Sorry David, I'm saying task record can be saved without putting an account but it cannot be saved without a contact(WHoID is required field for task ). So i'm trying to query to get whatID from WhoID.

Comment: I can't solve bulkification in a comment thread, @Vksfdc. I really encourage you to do the Trailhead module. You need to move that query out of the loop to stay within limits, and the module will teach you the patterns involved.